# Why do I get 251 square dm the correct answer is 252 square dm? (Error by a fraction)

Tags: geometry, trigonometry

I am sorry if I am bothering you folks, I've recently started to play with Trigonometry, it's really cool, but trying to understand what mistakes I am making, anyhow, I am guessing that I shall use the Pythagorean Theorem.

[image]

Here's what I have done:

$(a)^2 + (10.9)^2 = (25.6)^2$

$a^2 + 118.81 = 655.36$

$a^2 + 118.81 -118.81 = 655.36 - 118.81$

$a^2 = 536.55 \implies \sqrt{a} = \pm \sqrt{536.55} = 23$

$a = 23$

$\text{Area} = 10.9 \times 23 \approx 251 (250.7)$

What's wrong, a fraction is missing or maybe I shall use Trigonometry instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You rounded $\sqrt{536.66}$ to 23, while you should have left it as $23.16$ (or $23.2$).

Comment: Hi, hmm, tested with one single fraction, 23.1 and I'll get 251.79 ~ 252, because 23.2 gives 252.88 ~ 253, I am not sure, or? Is this more correct? Thanks a lot.

Comment: $23.16$ is closer to $23.2$ than to $23.1$.  This is becoming less a trigonometry problem and more a rounding problem.

Comment: Yes, but 23.16 is closest in output value, anyhow, thanks a lot @vadim123